Problem with openMP using self defined reduction
I'm trying to use a reduction for a complex<double> type with OpenMP but I get the following error in compilation:
test_reduction.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_reduction.cpp:26:65: error: user defined reduction not found for ‘sum’
26 |     #pragma omp parallel for reduction(complex_double_reduction:sum)

Here is the original code:
#include <omp.h>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

// Custom reduction operator for std::complex<double>
struct complex_double_reduction {
    typedef std::complex<double> value_type;

    static void init(value_type& val) {
        val = value_type(0, 0);
    }

    static void combine(value_type& dest, const value_type& src) {
        dest += src;
    }

    static void final(value_type& val) {
        // No action needed
    }
};

int main() {
    const int n = 100;
    std::complex<double> sum(0, 0);

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(complex_double_reduction:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::complex<double> val(i, -i);
        sum += val;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

I've tried to update gcc and used gcc 10, 11 and 12 in order to use OpenMP 5.0 (which to my understanding should support this reduction), but they all use OpenMP 4.5.
Is there a way to update to OpenMP 5.0 that I am missing?
Or alternatively, is there a way to use OpenMP 4.5 with this code?

Since you're using C++ and you define a struct anyway, define the operator+ on your struct, and you can actually do reduction(+:my_reduct_object). OpenMP plays unexpectedly nice with C++!

Compiler support for OpenMP standard versions is typically not binary, i.e. according to the official page: "Since GCC 11, [...] OpenMP 5.0 support has been extended for C, C++ and Fortran. GCC 12 has the initial support of OpenMP 5.1 and extends the OpenMP 5.0 coverage. GCC 13 implements several of the OpenMP 5.2 features and extends the OpenMP 5.0 and 5.1 support."

@VictorEijkhout I think you skimmed through the code a bit to quickly. The class that is supposed to be reduced is std::complex<double> which does have addition operators but still seems to require a custom reduction. No idea where that struct comes from... Maybe ChatGPT?

I don't know where you got that struct syntax from. That doesn't look very OpenMP-like but maybe I just don't know that. Anyway, this is how you define a custom reduction in OpenMP-4.
#pragma omp declare reduction \
    (complex_double_reduction : std::complex<double> : omp_out += omp_in) \
    initializer(omp_priv = std::complex<double>(0, 0))

int main() {
    const int n = 100;
    std::complex<double> sum(0, 0);

#   pragma omp parallel for reduction(complex_double_reduction:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::complex<double> val(i, -i);
        sum += val;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The initializer clause is optional and usually not needed.
Not all compilers require a custom reduction operator if the + operator is overloaded for the relevant type. In clang-16 you can just write reduction(+:sum) but this behavior is not portable at the moment.

That last sentence makes no sense as std::complex defines the necessary addition operators but reduction(+: sum) does not compile without a custom reduction. Maybe OpenMP struggles with the initialization of the local sums.

@paleonix It seems to work in newer Clang versions. https://godbolt.org/z/WWe8j5761 I didn't check beforehand and will qualify the statement
